# Triggering HTTP Errors: 4xx 5xx via HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, http, .htaccess

Is there any method in HTML or PHP to force-trigger specific HTTP 1.1 errors, such as 404, 403, 400, 500, etc.?  I need a method to test an `.htaccess` setup for error docs on a site on one of my servers.

Comment: Which SAPI interface is your server using?

Comment: @hakre you'll have to forgive me about a lack of server config information - I did not configure the server, so I don't have that information.

Comment: No need to change configuration, just to read it: [`php_sapi_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [header](http://php.net/header) function, example:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", TRUE, 404);
```

Examples: [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm)!

Comment: Since when was that the way to send status codes? I've never heard of a `Status:` header...

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp: Setting the status code itself might be useful as well, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, as you would for any other HTTP header.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die;
```

You can basically write whatever you want after the status code, it should still work the same.